# Connecting secondary router rises ping of whole network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I have a simple internet setup with 150 Mb/s and 10-20 ping when working correctly, but when connecting a specific secondary router, the ping rises to 100-120 ms. Download/upload speeds aren't badly affected. I need separate networks for each room, and this works fine, for the most part.

*Internet speed when secondary router isn't connected* (https://www.speedtest.net/my-result/d/51df3128-a906-4c9e-aacf-122c280a66fd)

*Internet speed when secondary router is connected* (https://www.speedtest.net/my-result/d/372a3d7c-4dd8-4912-a2e9-bd4bba258a15)

*Image of internet setup* (https://i.stack.imgur.com/06lIc.png)

The internet speed and ping are very good, unless a specific secondary router is connected to the primary one. When disconnected, the ping is very stable, ranging from 2-15 ms. However, when connecting the secondary router, it becomes highly variable, normally ranging from 100-200 ms.

I have tested internet speeds on several occasions, connecting and disconnecting all of the secondary routers to narrow the issue to one secondary router (everything works perfectly unless it is connected).

This router has wifi cameras connected to it, but I doubt the issue is caused by them (I have disconnected them and arrived to the same speeds and ping). The ping rises whether someone is using devices on said room or not (it stays the same when in usage and when no one is connected to that network).

I've had this issue a long time, and I'm not sure if I can somehow limit the "output" of a specific LAN port or if there is any other kind of solution to the issue.

It's worth noting I've tested these speeds using direct connections both  via LAN and wifi, to the primary router, as well as one of the secondary routers (not the problematic one).

Comment: Do any routers share the same IP address, and how are you connecting to the routers? (Wifi?)  If via WIFI, do you have a common SSID?